# Using public key with OSXFUSE

Tags: macos, filesystem, ssh

I have been allotted a system-generated password (which is impossible to remember) that I cannot change and every time I mount a folder from the remote machine, I have to enter the password for that account.

I have set-up a public key based log-in which works fine when I use `ssh`. That is, I do not have to enter the password when I am using `ssh`.

However, when I use OSXFUSE to mount a folder, I am asked for the password every time. How do I make OSXFUSE to use the public key for mounting the folder?

Command that I use to mount the folder:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/droplet
```

Comment: Have you opened an issue for this on the product's Github page?  There's already a few related issues there.

Comment: I found a related issue and tried out the suggestions given there in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

After trying some suggestions from https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/341 (An open issue for OSXFUSE), the following command worked for me -

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Use of option -K:

```
 -K      When adding identities, each passphrase will also be stored in the user's keychain.  When
         removing identities with -d, each passphrase will be removed from it.
```

Comment: Good answer. Lots of questions here on ssh-add for others needing help. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142463/terminal-wont-ask-for-passphrase-and-not-stored-in-keychain and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246243/how-can-i-use-an-ssh-key-with-a-passphrase-but-not-have-to-type-the-passphrase-e